# returning a string literal to const String reference in C++

Tags: c++, string

When compiling the following code the compiler issue the warning `warning: returning reference to temporary`

```
const string& example1()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

This code does not even compile:

```
void example2(){
    const string& str = "Hello";
}
```

and this one is valid since we know that a literal string is initialized into read-only memory segment by the compiler.

```
char* example3()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

Could you please help me understand what happen behind the scene when compiling the method `example1()` ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Since the method return an `std::string`, a temporary `std::string` is creating from the string literal. This temporary is destroyed at the end of the function scope.

Comment: example2 is working well for me. https://godbolt.org/z/jLFexp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Return "Hello"` creates a temporary `std::string` which will be deleted at the end of your function. Here, you are returning a reference on a `std::string` that won't exist at the end of the function call.

To solve that you can change the return type of `example1()` to `string`

Comment: Preferably just `string` without `const`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jerome and Zenith. But how come then a temporary string is not created in the case of example2() ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jerome's answer, you can also do this if you only want to have a single copy of the string:

```
const string& example1()
{
    static string example = "Hello";
    return example;
}
```

(Now `example` is a *static function variable*, and will also exist outside the function.)